# validate Select is not working with error in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select boxes, one named(ID) "Language" and another "time". I pasted my code below. If value is 0 it need to show an error(red color), but now it's showing green color. Otherwise it's working.

```
<div class="field_wrap">
    <select name="language" id="language" onblur="validateSelect(language)" class="select_promo">  
        <option value="0" disabled selected>Prefered Language</option>
        <option value="1">English</option>  
        <option value="2">Hindi</option>
        <option value="3">Tamil</option>
        <option value="4">Malayalam</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Script for language:

```
function validateSelect(language)
{    
    var myValue = document.getElementById('language').value; 
    if(myValue.length > 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('language').style.borderColor ='#80c75a';
        document.getElementById('languageError').style.display = "none";
        return true;  
    }
    else
    {   
        document.getElementById('language').style.borderColor ='#e35152';
        return false;  
    }
}
```

Looking forward to some ones reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking the length of languages value, which is in your case everytime 1.  you must check value itself.

Comment: 0 as a string even has the length 1

Comment: I checked both value and length, but not get the result

Comment: I tried value instead of length, it works. I pasted the code below but another issue is I added another selection for time can I use duplicate of this code?

Comment: My current code 'function validateSelect(language){ 
   var myValue = document.getElementById('language').value;
   if(myValue > 0){
    document.getElementById('language').style.borderColor ='#80c75a';
    document.getElementById('languageError').style.display = "none";
    return true;
  }else{
   document.getElementById('language').style.borderColor ='#e35152';
    return false;
  }
}'

Comment: I use the changed code by the way I listed below (both codes). But one problem when I click on language without select anything the error appears in time section.

Comment: function validateSelect(time){ 
   var myValue = document.getElementById('time').value;
   if(myValue > 0){
    document.getElementById('time').style.borderColor ='#80c75a';
    document.getElementById('timeError').style.display = "none";
    return true;
  }else{
   document.getElementById('time').style.borderColor ='#e35152';
    return false;
  }}

Comment: You Are giving a never used variable to the function. Your language stands in quotation marks, so you will change the element with the id language ans not time.